# How do I write an efficient Cosmos DB query to search for null values in an array?

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to search for all the items in my Cosmos DB that have a `name` value of `null` in a `users` array but this query seems like it's very inefficient and takes over 15 seconds to run and uses over 700 RU's:

```
SELECT * FROM root r
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.users, { 'name': null }, true)
```

However, this only happens when searching for items that contain a name that's null.  When I run the same query looking for items that contain a specific name the search only takes a few seconds and is closer to 50 RU's:

```
SELECT * FROM root r
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.users, { 'name': 'example' }, true)
```

Is there anything I can do to make searching for null values in an array more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your document,but you can try this sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id,r.users FROM root r JOIN u IN r.users WHERE IS_NULL(u.name)
```

Hope it can help you.